# Stored procedure to update a table based on data from table parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to begin by stating I'm an SQL noob, so I'd appreciate any suggestions or comments on my workflow and/or mindset when trying to solve this issue.

What I'm doing is gathering usage statistics about several applications, in several categories (not all categories necessarily apply to all applications), storing them in a database.

I've set up a few tables to do that, and then one table to link everything together that's structured like so (from now on: **Dtable**):

```
(column name - details)  
UserID  - foreign key to another table which stores users data  
ApplicationID - foreign key to another table which stores applications data  
CategoryID - foreign key to another table which holds a list of different categories  
Value - the actual data
```

Each application gathers the data, then submits it to the database using a stored procedure. As the amount of data can be different based on actual usage (not always sending every category) and for each application, I was thinking of sending the data as a DataTable with a list of *CategoryID* and *Value* so I won't have to call a procedure for every individual category (**Ptable**).

I need to update each record in **Dtable** to the correct value in **Ptable** according to *CategoryID*, but also filtered by *UserID* and *ApplicationID*. *UserID* and *ApplicationID* will be given as two other parameters to the Stored Procedure. **Ptable** only contains a list of *CategoryID* / *Value* records.

Now, I read about Cursors (for each record in the table parameter set the relevant data in the database table), but the consensus seems to be "Avoid at all costs".

How would I go about updating the table, then, based on the varying records in **Ptable**?

P.S.
The tables are structured like so to keep agility and scalability in adding more categories/applications in the future. If there's a better way to do it I'll be happy to know.

Comment: In Dtable, is there only one Value for a particular combination of UserID, ApplicationID, and CategoryID?

Comment: @Zach Esposito:   
There could be several values for the same UserID and ApplicationID, but only one per UserID AND ApplicationID AND CategoryID.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you'd need all three IDs to know which Value to update, does Ptable also contain UserID and ApplicationID?

Comment: @Zach Esposito:  The UserID and ApplicationID will be sent as two other parameters to the stored procedure, and remain the same. The idea is to update all categories that belong to that single user for that single application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the update statement would look something like this, where `@ApplicationID` and `@UserID` are the stored proc's other parameters:

```
update Dtable
    set Dtable.Value = p.Value
    from Ptable p
    where Dtable.UserID = @UserID
        and Dtable.ApplicationID = @ApplicationID
        and Dtable.CategoryID = p.CategoryID;
```

Comment: Fiddle (which is really neat and I wish I knew about it before, thanks for that as well!) seems to work as advertised. :)

Thank you @Zach Esposito!